# Hot to prefill antd V4 Form.List with data from array?

Tags: reactjs, antd

how can I extend example of usage `Form.List` from documentation https://codesandbox.io/s/nuhh3 ?
How can I make it render with some rows of inputs which values are prefilled from some array with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding `initialValues` prop for `Form` component like this

```
<Form
  name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
  initialValues={{
    users: [
      {first: 'Im', last: 'Okay'}
    ]
  }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
  autoComplete="off"
>
```

Of course you should put it in a variable and not type it up directly into the component. This is just an example.